# If $ 2<x^2<3$ then find then no of solutions which satisfy that $({x^2})=1/(x)$

Tags: functions

If $$ 2<x^2<3$$ then find then no of solutions which satisfy that $$({x^2})=1/(x)$$

where (x) stands for fractional part.!

I tried to convert it into greatest integer but i got no solution.!!is there any solution?p;z prove it?

Comment: This may not help much but all i could see is $[x^2]\neq [x]^2$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, both $(x^2)$ and $(x)$ are not greater than $1$, so there cannot be a solution unless both are in fact equal to $1$. But that cannot be, since there is no integer between $2$ and $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

$2<x^2 <3$ then what would be integral part of $x^2$?

$\sqrt{2}<x < \sqrt{3}$ then what would be integral part of $x$?

(I took only positive roots negative roots may be considered)